# Spring Boot And Jquery accesing values from a hashmap on the front end

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-boot

I have a rest controller in spring boot which returns a hash map where the key is an integer and the value is a string.My problem is that i need to show those values inside the page using jquery but i don't know how to access those values from that map:(
Here is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Map sendMoney(@RequestParam String email, @RequestParam int money) {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User loggedInUser = userRepository.findByEmail(auth.getName());
        Map<Integer,String> returnedValues = new HashMap<>();
        returnedValues.put(loggedInUser.getTotalMoney(), "Something went wrong");
        String message = "";
        if (money < 1) {
            returnedValues.put(loggedInUser.getTotalMoney(), "You can't send 0 money");
            return returnedValues;
        }
        if (user == null) {
            returnedValues.put(loggedInUser.getTotalMoney(), "This user doesn't exist");
            return returnedValues;
        }
        if (user != null && money >= 1) {
            if (!email.equals(auth.getName()) && money >= 1) {
                if (money > loggedInUser.getTotalMoney()) {
                    returnedValues.put(loggedInUser.getTotalMoney(), "You can't send that much money");
                    return returnedValues;
                } else {
                    loggedInUser.setTotalMoney(loggedInUser.getTotalMoney()-money);
                    user.setTotalMoney(user.getTotalMoney() + money);
                    userRepository.save(user);
                    userRepository.save(loggedInUser);
                    returnedValues.put(loggedInUser.getTotalMoney(), "Money sent successfully");
                    return returnedValues;
                }
            }
        }
        return returnedValues;
    }
```

JQuery:

```
function ajaxPost(){
         $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "/send",
              contentType: 'application/json',
              data: { 
                  'email': $('#email').val(),
                  'money': $('#money').val(),
              },
              success: function(data) {
                  console.log("SUCCES");
                  console.log(data);
                  $('.currentBalance').text(data[0]);
                $('#response').append('<h3>' + data[1] + '</h3>');
              },
              error : function(e) {
                    alert("Error!")
                    console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                }
            });
     }
```

So console.log(data) -> shows the hash map in the console like this:

```
{2165: "Money sent successfully", 2167: "Something went wrong"}
```

How can i access the key and the value of that object? I've tried with data[0] and other similar combinations and it didn't really worked:(

My html page has a h3 tag:

```
<h3 class="currentBalance" th:text="'Your current balance is: ' + ${money}"></h3>
```

So, using jquery i have to modify the text from currentBalance with the text that comes from the hashMap.
I've tried doing this:

```
$('.currentBalance').text(data[0]);
```

But data[0] it's not working:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the sample code :

```
data = {2165: "Money sent successfully", 2167: "Something went wrong"};
var idx = 0; 
var key = Object.keys(data)[idx];
var value = data[key]
console.log(value);
$('.currentBalance').text(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet:

```
for (var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + data[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need to iterate through the map i just need to show the first value:( basically i need to modify this $('.currentBalance').text(data[0]); with the key value from the data

Comment: @TruicaSorin : Please update your question with html code.